# PIC24ADC_with_LM358opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, pic, adc

I am converting 5V input voltage down to 3V because PIC24E ADC can take voltage input 0-3V. The PIC24E data sheet says that input source impedance of ADC should be a max of 200 ohm.  For this reason, I have made a resistive divider with opamp LM358 at the ouput. Can anyone recommend is it a good solution? Plus, after looking at the data sheet of LM358, there is information about output source and sink current which I am not able to understand. The images are attached in the question below. My PIC ADC requires 3.2 mA current in 12 bit operation but  9 mA current in 10 bit operation.[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: "*My PIC ADC requires 3.2 Amp current in 12 bit operation but 9 Amp current in 10 bit operation.*" There is something very wrong in that sentence. Do you mean mA or µA? Note 'A' or 'amp', 'V' or 'volt'. Units named after a person are lowercase when spelled out.

Comment: Harry, I am trying to read analog voltage 0-3V using my PIC ADC. 
@Transistor, Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have edited my question

Comment: @Najam No, you are trying to power your ADC with an op-amp. Right?

Comment: yes, after voltage divider circuit, op amp is connected. The output of opamp is connected to  input pin of PIC

Comment: @Najam Your question is so confusing, I'm amazed that you somehow have gathered two answers.

Comment: yes i know, it is confusing but thanks to @andy. He has given me some very important hints which are helpful in finding the solution.

Comment: Not gonna tilt my head sideways.

Answer (score 3):

You have correctly potted down 5 volts to 3 volts but unfortunately the LM358 is not guaranteed to be able to deliver 3 volts at the output when powered from a 5 volt supply rail. It's in the DS extract in your question. The specific DS area talks about a typical output of 28 volts when the positive rail is at 30 volts above the negative rail and, this means that when the supply voltage is only +5 volts, you can typically expect an output of +3 volts but it's not guaranteed to be greater than +2 volts.

Also you have not specified your performance requirements and the input offset voltage could be as high as +/-5 mV - that's an error of +/-0.16%.

I'd go for a rail-to-rail op-amp that overcomes the significant problem of being able to deliver +3 volts.

Take note also figure 11 in the LM358 data sheet and how miserably poor that device is at sinking current away from your charged ADC input capacitor when the output is meant to be close to 0 volts. However, you haven't specified performance expectations so I can't say whether this is a problem or not.